# const vector of iterators in c++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, constants, const-iterator

If I have a vector that contains iterators of another vector.

For example :

```
vector<vector<int>::iterator> vec;
```

what happens when passing this vector in const refrence?

For example:

```
void fun(const vector<vector<int>::iterator> &vec);
```

Are the elements of vec inside function fun const_iterator or iterator? can they be modified

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they aren't `const_iterator`. Chiefly because `const_iterator` is a user defined type that is related to `iterator` via a user defined conversion, and not in fact a const qualified `iterator`. <sup>(1)</sup>

What you access inside the function through the vector are `const iterator&`.

So you can use those to modify the elements referred by them.

The best analogy to this is that `const_iterator` is to `iterator`, what `const T*` is to `T*`. And what you have inside your function is akin to `T * const`.

---

<sub>(1) On paper, that is. For vectors it may very well be plain pointers in optimized code. In which case the analogy becomes the reality.</sub>